# Symfony 4 autowiring can't debug

Tags: autowired, symfony4

Something broke up with my autowiring. May someone help me find the reason. Debug command `bin/console debug:autowiring` produces error output:

```
In XmlFileLoader.php line 383:                                                                                                   
Unable to parse file ".../var/cache/dev/srcDevDebugProjectContainer.xml".                                                                                                 

In XmlUtils.php line 101:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[ERROR 1840] Element '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}argument',  attribute 'type': [facet 'enumeration'] The value 'binary' is not an element of the set {'collection', 'service', 'expression', 'string', 'constant', 'iterator', 'tagged'}. (in ... - line 4657, column 0)
[ERROR 1824] Element '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}argument', attribute 'type': 'binary' is not a valid value of the atomic type '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}argument_type'. (in ... - line 4657, column 0)
[ERROR 1840] Element '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}argument', attribute 'type': [facet 'enumeration'] The value 'binary' is not an element of the set {'collection', 'service', 'expression', 'string', 'constant', 'iterator', 'tagged'}. (in ... - line 4658, column 0)
[ERROR 1824] Element '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}argument', attribute 'type': 'binary' is not a valid value of the atomic type '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}argument_type'. (in ... - line 4658, column 0)
[ERROR 1840] Element '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}argument', attribute 'type': [facet 'enumeration'] The value 'binary' is not an element of the set {'collection', 'service', 'expression', 'string', 'constant', 'iterator', 'tagged'}. (in ... - line 4659, column 0)
[ERROR 1824] Element '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}argument', attribute 'type': 'binary' is not a valid value of the atomic type '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}argument_type'. (in ... - line 4659, column 0)
```

It may be a bug described [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25916) but there is no binary strings in my parameters. The other debug commands are working.

Comment: Have you tried removing the xml file? What happens afterwards?

Comment: Afterward the same xml file is created. But indeed now I found binary string in config. Sorry for the quick question. Now I expect negative voting :)

Comment: Sharing the answer + how did you find it in easily replicable way would bring more good :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is how I found the answer. Line 4657 in `srcDevDebugProjectContainer.xml` pointed me to locales section in parameters .yaml file

```
locales:
    de: "Deutsch\0000A0/\0000A0German"
    en: "English\0000A0/\0000A0English"
    lt: "Lietuvi\000173\0000A0/\0000A0Lithuanian"
    cs: "\00010Ce\000161tina\0000A0/\0000A0Czech"
```

I'm using it for language switch bar. I changed these to

```
locales:
    de: "Deutsch / German"
    en: "English / English"
    lt: "Lietuvių / Lithuanian"
    cs: "Čeština / Czech"
```

and now everything is working fine.